# Whats is better - storing a count in database or $size in aggregate?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on an application which has a MongoDB as backend and I want to know the number of sub-documents that are saved in a collection. So, there are two ways I can think of:

1. Storing a size in a parent document.

   - e.g. To save followers in a social media app, one needs a `followerList` as list of user ids and `followerCount` as integer i.e. the number of users in the `followerList`.
     So, the mongoose schema will be:

```
new Schema({
...
followerList: { type: [{ type: String, ref: 'user' }], default: [] },
followerCount: { type: Number, default: 0 },
...
})
```

and the push and pull operation will be as following:

```
// Push follower
findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: userId, followerList: { $ne: idToFollow } },
   { $push: { followerList: idToFollow }, $inc: { followerCount: 1 } }
)

// Pull follower
findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id: userId, followerList: idToUnfollow },
   { $pull: { followerList: idToUnfollow }, $inc: { followerCount: -1 } }
)
```

This way I can just pull `followerCount` directly from the database and use it.

2. Storing only `followerList` in database and get size using `$size` operator of MongoDB.

   - e.g. To get user profile and its follower count, I can use the following aggregation:

```
aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: userId } },
  { $addFields: { followerCount: { $size: "$followerList" } } },
])
```

Which one is better or is there any other better method?

**Added another type of data that is not subject to be changed easily..**

- If there is a data i.e. easily changeable like followers and following then we should go with the second option(i.e. use aggregate to count the sub-documents)
- If there is a data i.e. not easily changeable, e.g. a match that should update the following countable fields:

  - match count of the player
  - match count of the team
  - score count of the player
  - score count of the team
  - etc..

These type of data should be retrieved as following:

1. Calculate the count's when match end and save the calculated fields in the database. Retrieve it easily using calculated fields from the database.
2. Just end the match and calculate the required data at the time of retrieval. I think its a more cpu expensive tasks and the first option is preferable.

What do you think?

Comment: I’d never store something that’s subject to be changed often and / or is easily query able

Comment: the fastest way would be fetch all data (_id only) and count it in your script

Comment: Never say never Chris, you have a point that having one source of truth (in this case actually counting array size) is usually the better practice however i wouldn't dismiss maintaining the extra field of `followerCount` if it makes life easier in certain situations. With that said data received from these kind of fields should not be treated as reliable if it involves a sensitive operation.

Comment: So, if anything that's subject to be changed often and for having one source of truth, I should go with either "using $size operator" or "count it in the script". The first option, I think is more preferable because if any user has 1000+ followers then I don't think we should retrieve all 1000+ _id's and count it in the script. Am I right @mehta-rohan ?

Comment: I think storing follower count is a better option.

Comment: If we will store a count in the database then - Is MongoDB will handle such a frequent updates like follow-following easily? Isn't there will be a performance issue? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: If `followerCount` is something very important (very frequently used), say whenever you want to fetch `followerList` it should have the count as well then its better stored in db because you are making the db roundtrip anyways and does not make sense to compute length in script or aggreagtion when it could've been easily there. That's how I'll decide.

Comment: Actually, whenever user fetch the profile then it will get all counts to show on UI like number of followers, followings, blocked users, likes, comments etc.. but when user click on the count then it needs to fetch the actual list with paging..